# remove comma from last line

Tags: sed, awk, grep

How do I remove the comma from the last line of the file?
Here is the file:

```
# cat ox_data_archive_r_20120727.json
{"name": "secondary_ua","type":"STRING"},
{"name": "request_ip","type":"STRING"},
{"name": "cb","type":"STRING"},
```

The following will remove the comma from all 3 lines.

```
# sed 's/,$/\ /' ox_data_archive_r_20120727.json
{"name": "secondary_ua","type":"STRING"}
{"name": "request_ip","type":"STRING"}
{"name": "cb","type":"STRING"}
```

I need to remove the last comma only. So the output should look something like this...

```
# cat newfile.json
{"name": "secondary_ua","type":"STRING"},
{"name": "request_ip","type":"STRING"},
{"name": "cb","type":"STRING"}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$ cat input.txt
{"name": "secondary_ua","type":"STRING"},
{"name": "request_ip","type":"STRING"},
{"name": "cb","type":"STRING"},
$ sed '$s/,$//' < input.txt
{"name": "secondary_ua","type":"STRING"},
{"name": "request_ip","type":"STRING"},
{"name": "cb","type":"STRING"}
```

From the documentation of [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html#Addresses):

> `$`: This address matches the last line of the last file of input, or the last line of each file when the `-i` or `-s` options are specified.

Comment: Note for Mac and Unix users: This also works for BSD sed.

Comment: Works for me.Great answer !

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
sed '$ s/,$//g' input_file
```

- The first `$` selects the last line.

You could add `-i` and `sed` will apply the changes to your `input_file`.

Answer (score 0):

The awk answer is certainly more verbose than the sed:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print prev} {prev=$0} END {sub(/,$/,"", prev); print prev}' file
```